# How can I monitor recurrent rake tasks run by heroku scheduler?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, monitoring, scheduler, newrelic

I just got the last month heroku bill, and the scheduled rake tasks were a relatively heavy burden. We are pretty early in our development process, so we just developed some rake tasks to get the job done recently, and didn't had much concern in theirs optimization.

Now we want to improve theirs performance and theirs heroku processing hours usage. We use New Relic to monitor the webapp performance, but apparently this type of rake tasks are ignored by default, and it's unclear how to override that.

Anyone had a similiar problem? How can I track the scheduled tasks in close to real time to monitor performance, optimize, and don't get suprise bills?

Comment: What sort of processing are you doing?  If you're doing it right, you should be working each worker flat out before needing to scale it, so therefore your 'surprise bills' should never be more than $30-40 from normal.

Comment: It is using just one worker per task, so we got a bill on that price range, which is low overall, but high for us on the context of a unreleased app with half-dozen users. We expect to process much more data in the short-term, so we want to optimize now, before we got a really bad surprise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whilst you can't really monitor rake tasks that well, there are a few little things you can do. One is the use of logging.  Output start and end times of tasks to logs, and you can then see what's been happening duration wise.  If you couple this with something like the Papertrail add-on then you can do additional interrogation later on.

As for running the jobs themselves, there's a couple of ways that you can run background processes which are dependant on how they need to run:

If you're needing to run jobs on a schedule, there's a few options available.  Firstly there's the Heroku scheduler, which is pretty good, but doesn't guarantee executions will happen.  Normally you would use this to kick off a rake task which will bring up a one-off dyno for the duration of the task - therefore you need to ensure in development that these tasks are as efficient as possible.

Alternatively, if you're looking at jobs that need a little more control or using a clock process.  Essentially this is a dyno running 24/7 that does nothing but kick off other jobs at preset intervals and times.  This would normally be done using the clockwork gem.  The downside of this approach is that you need to pay for a clock process all the time.

A third approach, and one that might work is delayed job, with it's `runat` option, allowing you to queue a job to be run in the future (and jobs can re-queue themselves).  There are a few issues with this in that a failure can kill the whole chain, and you need a full time worker running to process them all.

Therefore, in order to minimize your bills, ensure that your rake tasks are as performant and reliable, and then choose the scheduling option that suits you.  If you're looking at schedules plus user created events, delayed_job might be the best option.  If you're looking at a few tasks running periodically, then go scheduler.  If you're looking at running lots of time critical jobs on a regular basis, go with clockwork.

Either way, you should be able to constrain a fair amount of processing into just one or two processes depending on your approach.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We ended up moving to a mix of Heroku Scheduler and Resque, while forcing the new relic agent to start in order to keep better track of things.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is almost 10 years old, but there is a new way!

You can now monitor your Heroku Scheduler jobs using [One-off Dyno Metrics](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/one-off-metrics). This Heroku add-on gathers metrics for all detached one-off dynos running in your Heroku app. It was created to be an extension of Heroku's Application Metrics and works out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

when you are running on heroku cedar there is a way to get a free setup for your workers. this is no answer to your monitoring question, but it might be interesting anyways: http://blog.nofail.de/2011/07/heroku-cedar-background-jobs-for-free/

Answer (score 0):

You can [force the New Relic agent to start](http://newrelic.com/docs/ruby/force-the-ruby-agent-to-start) in your rake tasks and report their performance data.

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer to the specific question,but...
One method of reducing overhead is using Unicorn server to get multiple workers working on one dyno. It depends on your set up, but most people who've taken the time to test it can comfortably get 3 - 4 worker processes running concurrently. It's a huge boost in clearing cues or tasks. Just be careful not to max out the allocated memory for the dyno.